# append class if selected simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to add a class to each radio field in my form, when it is selected. I followed the steps for documentation for custom inputs, but it didn't work. Do I just need to do this with `JS`?

**What I tried:**

```
# app/inputs/collection_select_input.rb
class CollectionSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput
  def input_html_classes
    super.push('chosen')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't use pure ruby to do this. `Ruby on Rails` is a server side language, and for this kind of job, you can't use it, you should definitely use `Javascript`.

Using `Jquery` for instance, assuming your radio field got the `radio` class, and you wish it to get the `newclass` class on clicked:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('newclass');
});
```